# Spring Cloudstream 3 + RabbitMQ configuration to existing queue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-amqp

I'm learning Cloudstream and cannot map the cloudstream `Function<String, String>` into existing queue.
I'm just creating the hello world app from spring cloud documentation, but don't really understand [this part regarding binding names](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_functional_binding_names).

I have `q.test` (existing) on my rabbitmq app, but when I use this code and configuration, my app always create new queue `q.test.anonymous.someRandomString`.

Anybody has configuration example for this?

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class CloudstreamApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudstreamApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> uppercase() {
        return value -> {
            System.out.println("Received: " + value);
            return value.toUpperCase();
        };
    }

}
```

application.yml

```
spring.cloud.stream:
  function.bindings: 
    uppercase-in-0: q.test
  bindings:
    uppercase-in-0.destination: q.test
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the binder documentation - Using Existing Queues/Exchanges](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_using_existing_queuesexchanges).

> If you have an existing exchange/queue that you wish to use, you can completely disable automatic provisioning as follows, assuming the exchange is named `myExchange` and the queue is named `myQueue`:
>
> `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<binding name>.destination=myExhange`
>
> `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<binding name>.group=myQueue`
>
> `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.<binding name>.consumer.bindQueue=false`
>
> `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.<binding name>.consumer.declareExchange=false`
>
> `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.<binding name>.consumer.queueNameGroupOnly=true`